# java NullPointerException Android Handler

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-handler

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   
    Handler myHandler;
    Runnable myRunnable;
    TextView tv;
    int no;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    public void initialize(){
        no = 10;
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        myRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText(Integer.toString(no));
                no--;
                if(no != 0)
                myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I tried forcing the Orientation to portrait to run this code but it failed again.

Whenever i try a handler to basically change the view text after every second i get this error.

Am new to Android development a college student so bear with my mistakes if any.

Thank you in advance.

The logs are below.

```
    10-04 04:22:35.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    10-04 04:22:35.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{we.funnycorps.handlerpractise/we.funnycorps.handlerpractise.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

    10-04 04:22:35.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

    10-04 04:22:35.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
```

Comment: Where did u call the `initialize` method. u should call it in onCreate

Comment: you have not initialized myHandler nor have a call for initialize() method anywhere so both are NULL at the time of call myHandler.post(myRunnable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myHandler is not being initialised, and since the initialize() method isn't being called in your onCreate(), myRunnable is also not initialised before you try to post it.

Answer (score 2):

you have not used the `initialize()` function in oncreate ,below code use ,you will get the expected result.

```
public class Dummycls extends Activity {

Handler myHandler;
Runnable myRunnable;
TextView tv;
int no;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
initialize();
//myHandler.post(myRunnable);
}

public void initialize(){
no = 10;
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinchTitleText);

myHandler=new Handler();
myRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(no));
        no--;
        if(no != 0)
        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);

        //handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);


    }
}; 
myHandler.post(myRunnable);


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize `myHandler` as

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

i.e. replace

```
Handler myHandler;
```

to

```
 Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

And call `initialize()` method before `myHandler.post(myRunnable);` as

```
initialize();
myHandler.post(myRunnable);
```